# Add Google Cloud service account to Google Play Console Api Access

Tags: react-native

is it possibe to add a Google Cloud service account json done with a different gmail account to a Google Play console api access with different gmail account?

Google Cloud service account (gmail1) -> Google Play Api Access (gmail2)
I want to use an already existing cloud platform profile, only thing is I created Google Play console profile with another gmail, is it possible to manually add the json?
https://play.google.com/console/u/0/developers/7136348775757715460/api-access
Can't do it from here...